# running setState right before submit is not submitting the correct information due to it being asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to run a function before setting state when the user clicks submit, but due to it being asynchronous I'm not getting the information that I'm looking for. The function splits a string into an array that is then set in state right before submit:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({ title: '', description: '', tags: [] });
const [tagInput, setTagInput] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPost((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      tags: [
        ...tagInput
          .split(',')
          .splice(2)
          .map((value) => value.trim().replace(/[\W_]+/g, '')),
      ],
    }));
   createPost(post)
          .then((response) => console.log(response))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

these values are coming from an input that holds 'tags' that the user submits.

```
<input
  type='text'
  placeholder='politics, humanitarian, nationalParks'
  name='tags'
  className='post-form-input'
  value={tagInput}
  onChange={handleTagInput}
/>
```

the value of that input is set to another state:

```
const [tagInput, setTagInput] = useState('');
```

which as shown above is then parsed and set into my 'post' state. `onSubmit()` I'm losing the tags, they aren't saving. How can I implement this to get the array to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three options you could do:

1. Remove the createPost part from handleSubmit, create a useEffect
   that depends on post and if post is valid you send them from there.
2. Create a useEffect that depends on tagInput and updates post
   accordingly, so post would be ready when you submit.
3. Update post directly from handleTagInput, which I guess sets the
   tagInput, and post also would be ready on submit.